# AdBlock preventing one of my pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, adblock

We have an html page, and the javascript libraries used for that page are chosen.js and cgnotify both of which we are using in other pages. There is no content marked and named as "ad" or anything containing "ad" but adblock for no reason blocks it. 
I fully erased the page content and tried again and still it blocks the page. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: So maybe some other content shows that it's "ad"? Have you tried deleting block by block and see if it's working or not?

Comment: AdBlock matches some common ad words in the URL. Try renaming the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can go to the forums at http://easylist.adblock.org and let them know. They are usually pretty quick about addressing problems of this sort.

In the meantime, check your console and see if Adblock is causing any errors due to scripts not loading.

Typically (depending on your browser) when JavaScript hits a couple errors it will prevent subsequent scripts from executing. If you're using any JavaScript to render your page, it's possible that script is never executing due to Adblock creating errors higher on the page.

I'd be willing to bet you have an external script failing to load, and that's causing some dependency errors, so your page is never rendering.